# How to use Vue 3 & Add Plugin Boostrap-vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I try using Vue 3, but I look can't using Vue.use(exampleplugin) again.

I using command vue add bootstrap-vue after generate vue create project. And on plugin bootstrap-vue warning with code:

```
import Vue from "vue";

import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

Output warning terminal:

> warning  in ./src/plugins/bootstrap-vue.js
>
> "export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'
>
> warning  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/utils/vue.js
>
> "export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

What's wrong with that? And how do I use vue 3 to add plugin bootstrap-vue?

Comment: Pretty sure [BootstrapVue isn't compatible with Vue 3](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196) yet. You should probably stick with Vue 2

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? I have the same problem but for a different library. Importing it in ‘main.js’ and chaining a .use to the createApp call doesn’t work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Bootstrap Vue is not yet ready for Vue 3.

To answer part of your question, Vue 3 changes the method for instantiating the application instance, including how plugins are registered.

For example...

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import Router from './router/Router';

createApp({/* options */}})
  .use(Router)
  .mount('#app');
```

You can read more about this at the official docs.

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html

https://v3-migration.vuejs.org

Comment: Is this still the case? Is bootstrap vue not compatible with vue 3?

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap-Vue states they are compatible with vue 2.6: https://bootstrap-vue.org/

Answer (score 4):

For vue 3 you can use
[bootstrap-vue-3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-vue-3)
Install: `npm i bootstrap-vue-3`
Config:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import BootstrapVue3 from "bootstrap-vue-3";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue-3/dist/bootstrap-vue-3.css";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(BootstrapVue3);
app.mount("#app");
```

Comment: Keep in mind it's not yet ready for production though.

Comment: This package is deprecated!

Comment: ```This package is deprecated and the repo was moved to bootstrap-vue organization. For updates on this project go to bootstrap-vue. The new package is called bootstrap-vue-next. Thanks for your support!
```
https://github.com/bootstrap-vue-next/bootstrap-vue-next