# Im having a problem in vuejs while importing vue-bootstrap

Tags: vue.js

I've got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdBWx.png) in console: `Uncaught TypeError: _vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is undefined`.

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import Vue from "vue";

import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app");
```

Comment: Are you running Vue 3? Because BootstrapVue is not compatible with Vue 3 yet.

Comment: yes it Vue 3.. are u sure vue 3 is the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Vue 3 & Add Plugin Boostrap-vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63570340/how-to-use-vue-3-add-plugin-boostrap-vue)